# ASPX page with a User Control not working with localization

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, localization

I have a project that is using ASPX and C#.  All of the pages support localization through the overridden InitializeCulture method.  Everything works very well with the exception of one page.  This page has UserControl that is used for searching.  I have noticed something odd with this page.  If I execute a search, all of the French characters show up incorrectly.  However, if I change the language to English and then back to French they show up as they should.  The text is coming from a global resx file.
First display:

```
Nous avons Ã©galement effectuÃ©
```

After changing language and then back:

```
Nous avons également effectué
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  It affects the entire page too, even parts that work properly on all other pages.  The web.config file has the default encoding set to utf-8:

`<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you see two unrelated characters in place of a single character with a diacritic , you haven't told the client what it needs to know to treat the page as UTF-8, e.g.

```
Response.CodePage = 65001 ;
Response.CharSet = "utf-8" ;
```

This is excerpt from [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357759/accented-french-characters/2357797#2357797).

Comment: The post you quoted also has the very same line from the web.config file that I have shown above as an alternate solution.

Comment: But what about codepage? For example UTF-8 character encoding has code page numbers 1208 at IBM, 65001 at Microsoft, 4110 at SAP

Comment: Setting the codepage is not necessary when the request and response encodings are set in the web.config file.  Just for completeness, I added the codepage attribute to the page definition and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found several references to problems with French characters in UTF-8 in apparently unrelated apps:

- http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/37/189336.aspx
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,220789,220789

Maybe give UTF-16 a try?

Comment: That doesn't explain why it works after refreshing the page though.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea. But it looks like there's a problem with the actual character set...something about the refresh clears a buffer, or increments a counter past a magical value, who knows? I wouldn't even try to figure it out, just try another character set.