# asp.net sql query'ed text rendered with wrong charset

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, sql, character-encoding

I'm revamping an old .net 2 website, to get the look and feel of our new CI. Since there was money left over, I was told to review the code behind as well.

As of now, I ran into a serious problem with the charset: On almost all pages the German "special" characters like ß ä ö ü are rendered correct. But on one page every special character is rendered like a normal one. In this case ö --> o; ä--> a; ß --> ?

The text the query is grabbing from the database is rendered correctly in the debugger, but gets messed up as soon as its rendered in the browser.

I've set the charset in the master page to ISO-8859-1 as well as in config.web.

Help is much appreciated - thanks in advance.

Marco

Comment: I think you should check the below link might help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357759/accented-french-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem wasn't code related at all.
The admin who set up the machine, didnt use the normal Oracle client we normaly use. Instead he just copied over the instant client, set up the TNS_NAMES.ORA and was done with it.

This is wy, there never were Oracle entries in the registry, telling the client which charset to use.

Instead of bothering with it, I just pushed it through as an environmental var

```
    NLS_LANG = German.Germany.Charset.
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the metatag in the head section of the rendered HTML?

I.e. 
   < meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type">

Ah, sorry! I've misread the line about the masterpage.

Comment: No - sorry. Following the linked thread brought no solution.
In fact: It didn't change anything at all.

last thing I tried was to get rid of all charset declarations in the project. Didnt work either.