# How to display correctly italian accented letters?

Tags: asp.net, localization

in an aspx page “à” and “è” both are shown as “Ã”.

How to overcome the problem and se "à" and "è" instead?

Thanks a lot.

**Update**:

This is the context:

```
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvBLQTY"  ValidationGroup="SavingErrors" 
         Display="None" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Quantità Errata!."
         ClientValidationFunction = "ValidateQTY"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

The "Quantità errata" message displays as "QuantitÃ errata" in browser.

Comment: This is caused by a character encoding mismatch. There are many existing questions on such issues. Without further information, it is impossible to say which existing question best corresponds to this case, but I’ve made a guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [accented French characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2357759/accented-french-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the italian symbols and their differences - http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/italian.html

If you want à then use ALT+0224 and it will present it.
For Ã use ALT+0192, etc...

Comment: Most probably irrelevant, since the file *has* the characters, they just get displayed wrong or munged.